# How can I make this if-else statement into a switch statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Here is my if-else statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int number;
        System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");
        number = input.nextInt();
        if (number % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
        }
            else {
                System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
        }
    }
```

Comment: [The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: What do you need switch for? you either have divisioble or not

Comment: Smells like a homework assignment.  Why else would someone write code like this and then want to turn it into a switch statement.

Answer (score 6):

Never mind the switch - you don't need either.
You can make it into *one* statement:

```
System.out.println(number + " is" + (number % 7 == 0 ? "" : "n't") + " divisible by 7");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
number = input.nextInt();
switch(number % 7)
{
 case 0:
    System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
    break;

 default:
    System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 number = input.nextInt();
    a = number % 7

 switch (a) {
            case 0:   System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
                     break;

            default: System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
                     break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
    switch (number % 7) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
    }
```

OR

```
switch (number % 7) {
case 0:
    System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
    break;
case 1: // Fall through
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
    System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int number;
System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");
number = input.nextInt();
int tempNumber = number % 7;
switch(tempNumber) {
      case 0:
         System.out.println(number + " is divisible by 7");
         break;
      default :
         System.out.println(number + " isn't divisible by 7");
 }
```